# I need help making a java program that takes a number from 1-12 and outputs a month

Tags: java

"Write a program that asks the user for a number between 1 -12; the output will be the corresponding month.  Make sure to incorporate a while statement."-my teacher(the assignment)

I made most of this month calculator, but my teacher said I need a while loop. Any help with my program & while loops?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tester {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter month's number: ");

            int monthNumber;

            monthNumber = in.nextInt();

            if (monthNumber == 1)
                  System.out.println("January");
            else if (monthNumber == 2)
                  System.out.println("February");
            else if (monthNumber == 3)
                  System.out.println("March");
            else if (monthNumber == 4)
                  System.out.println("April");
            else if (monthNumber == 5)
                  System.out.println("May");
            else if (monthNumber == 6)
                  System.out.println("June");
            else if (monthNumber == 7)
                  System.out.println("July");
            else if (monthNumber == 8)
                  System.out.println("August");
            else if (monthNumber == 9)
                  System.out.println("September");
            else if (monthNumber == 10)
                  System.out.println("October");
            else if (monthNumber == 11)
                  System.out.println("November");
            else if (monthNumber == 12)
                  System.out.println("December");
            else
                  System.out.println("Invalid month.");
      }
}
```

‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

Comment: Why should this need any loop at all? Can you please [edit] your question and share the *actual* text of the exercise?

Comment: I guess because the user should get the possibility to try More than one time?

Comment: you should use array of string that have 12 month in it  instead if else if  to make it easy and get month bay index-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an infinite loop (e.g. `while(true){}`) and break it on some condition as shown in the following examples.

Also, instead of reinventing the wheel, you can use the in-built classes.

```
import java.time.DateTimeException;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter month's number or -1 to exit: ");
            int month = in.nextInt();
            if (month == -1) {
                break;
            }
            try {
                System.out.println(Month.of(month).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH));
            } catch (DateTimeException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid month");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter month's number or -1 to exit: 1
January
Enter month's number or -1 to exit: 9
September
Enter month's number or -1 to exit: 90
Invalid month
Enter month's number or -1 to exit: -1
```

Learn more about the date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Some other options:

You can use a `String[]` as shown below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                "October", "November", "December" };
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter month's number or -1 to exit: ");
            int month = in.nextInt();
            if (month == -1) {
                break;
            }
            if (month >= 1 && month <= 12) {
                System.out.println(months[month - 1]);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid month");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Another option:**

You can use `switch-case`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                "October", "November", "December" };
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter month's number or -1 to exit: ");
            int month = in.nextInt();
            if (month == -1) {
                break;
            }

            String monthName = "";
            switch (month) {
            case 1:
                monthName = "January";
                break;
            case 2:
                monthName = "February";
                break;
            case 3:
                monthName = "March";
                break;
            case 4:
                monthName = "April";
                break;
            case 5:
                monthName = "May";
                break;
            case 6:
                monthName = "June";
                break;
            case 7:
                monthName = "July";
                break;
            case 8:
                monthName = "August";
                break;
            case 9:
                monthName = "September";
                break;
            case 10:
                monthName = "October";
                break;
            case 11:
                monthName = "November";
                break;
            case 12:
                monthName = "December";
                break;
            default:
                monthName = "Invalid month";
            }
            System.out.println(monthName);
        }
    }
}
```

**Yet another option:**

You can use the ternary operator.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter month's number or -1 to exit: ");
            int month = in.nextInt();
            if (month == -1) {
                break;
            }

            String monthName = month == 1 ? "January"
                    : month == 2 ? "February"
                            : month == 3 ? "March"
                                    : month == 4 ? "April"
                                            : month == 5 ? "May"
                                                    : month == 6 ? "June"
                                                            : month == 7 ? "July"
                                                                    : month == 8 ? "August"
                                                                            : month == 9 ? "September"
                                                                                    : month == 10 ? "October"
                                                                                            : month == 11 ? "November"
                                                                                                    : month == 12
                                                                                                            ? "December"
                                                                                                            : "Invalid month";

            System.out.println(monthName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! All of these methods worked!!!

Answer (score -1):

You won't need any `while` loop because there's nothing to iterate on. Just use an array of months and pick up month name using the month index.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] monthList = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter month's number: ");
        int month = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(monthList[month - 1]);
    }
}
```